# Is it necessary to remove the primary secret GPG key from your laptop if it has full-disk encryption?

Tags: key-management, pgp, gnupg

According to a number of articles, e.g. "[Creating the Perfect GPG Keypair](https://alexcabal.com/creating-the-perfect-gpg-keypair/)," it is advisable to have a number of subkeys in your GPG key, one for encryption, and one for signing, and then to (a) back up your keys as well as a revocation certificate [ideally on paper too] and (b) remove the "primary" signing secret key from your laptop, so that `gpg -K` returns:

```
/home/bilbo/.gnupg/secring.gpg
-----------------------------
sec#  4096R/488BA441 2013-03-13
uid                  Bilbo Baggins <bilbo@shire.org>
ssb   4096R/69B0EA85 2013-03-13
ssb   4096R/C24C2CDA 2013-03-13
```

... with the goal being that if your laptop is stolen you can properly revoke the keys.

I use Filevault 2 on my Mac & also have a firmware password -- so hopefully if my laptop is stolen or lost, I won't have to be concerned that someone will be able to access the data. Is it truly necessary to remove the primary signing secret key? I'm mostly concerned that I will lose the backups of the secret key and thus lose access to the keys.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

Although you have taken good precautions against loss or theft of your laptop, you remain vulnerable to electronic attacks. In particular browser-based malware could take control of your computer and steal your PGP key.

The point of using subkeys is that you keep the master key somewhere really safe - which is not your everyday laptop. There have been [other questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51771/where-do-you-store-your-personal-private-gpg-key/51777#51777) on here about where to keep your keys safe. A popular suggestion was to print out a QR code encoding of your key, and keep the printout safe.